# macos terminal caching command execution

Tags: angular, zsh

I am not sure how to describe it, I and my colleague are expitiencing weired behavior in our project, the command execution is cached like:

> yarn build

the first time it takes ex. 10 minutes
the next time, it takes 1 second and

> Build at: 2023-03-29T10:09:10.352Z - Hash: a8f064e60c86c7e9 - Time: 105184ms

the same for other commands like

> npx ng test noah-os --coverage

after the first time it gets executed under 1 second, and the tests are not executed, they fail on server later...

What I have noticed, if I add any random option

> --browser=firefox1
> ...firefox2

in this case the execution work well, the first time

I am using the node 16, angular setup on mac with zshell, (bash is the same)
This is more or less new, we are out of ideas... not even what to google.

```
nx build noah-os
+omz_termsupport_preexec:1> [[ '' != true ]]
+omz_termsupport_preexec:3> emulate -L zsh
+omz_termsupport_preexec:4> setopt extended_glob
+omz_termsupport_preexec:7> local -a cmdargs
+omz_termsupport_preexec:8> cmdargs=( nx build noah-os ) 
+omz_termsupport_preexec:10> [[ nx = fg ]]
+omz_termsupport_preexec:44> local CMD=nx
+omz_termsupport_preexec:45> local LINE='nx build noah-os'
+omz_termsupport_preexec:47> title nx '%100>...>nx build noah-os%<<'
+title:1> setopt localoptions nopromptsubst
+title:4> [[ -n '' ]]
+title:8> : '%100>...>nx build noah-os%<<'
+title:10> case xterm-256color (cygwin | xterm*)
+title:12> print -Pn '\e]2;%100\>...\>nx\ build\ noah-os%\<\<\a'
+title:13> print -Pn '\e]1;nx\a'
+__vsc_preexec:1> PS1=$'%(?:%{\C-[[01;32m%}➜ :%{\C-[[01;31m%}➜ ) %{$fg[cyan]%}%c%{$reset_color%} $(git_prompt_info)' 
+__vsc_preexec:2> PS2='%_> ' 
+__vsc_preexec:3> [ -n '' ']'
+__vsc_preexec:6> __vsc_in_command_execution=1 
+__vsc_preexec:7> __vsc_current_command='nx build noah-os' 
+__vsc_preexec:8> __vsc_command_output_start
+__vsc_command_output_start:1> printf '\e]633;C\a'
+__vsc_command_output_start:2> __vsc_escape_value 'nx build noah-os'
+__vsc_escape_value:1> emulate -L zsh
+__vsc_escape_value:4> local 'LC_ALL=C' 'str=nx build noah-os' i byte token 'out='
+__vsc_escape_value:6> i = 0
+__vsc_escape_value:6> i < 16
+__vsc_escape_value:7> byte=n 
+__vsc_escape_value:10> [ n '=' '\' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:12> [ n '=' ';' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:15> token=n 
+__vsc_escape_value:18> out+=n 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> ++i 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> i < 16
+__vsc_escape_value:7> byte=x 
+__vsc_escape_value:10> [ x '=' '\' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:12> [ x '=' ';' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:15> token=x 
+__vsc_escape_value:18> out+=x 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> ++i 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> i < 16
+__vsc_escape_value:7> byte=' ' 
+__vsc_escape_value:10> [ ' ' '=' '\' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:12> [ ' ' '=' ';' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:15> token=' ' 
+__vsc_escape_value:18> out+=' ' 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> ++i 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> i < 16
+__vsc_escape_value:7> byte=b 
+__vsc_escape_value:10> [ b '=' '\' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:12> [ b '=' ';' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:15> token=b 
+__vsc_escape_value:18> out+=b 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> ++i 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> i < 16
+__vsc_escape_value:7> byte=u 
+__vsc_escape_value:10> [ u '=' '\' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:12> [ u '=' ';' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:15> token=u 
+__vsc_escape_value:18> out+=u 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> ++i 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> i < 16
+__vsc_escape_value:7> byte=i 
+__vsc_escape_value:10> [ i '=' '\' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:12> [ i '=' ';' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:15> token=i 
+__vsc_escape_value:18> out+=i 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> ++i 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> i < 16
+__vsc_escape_value:7> byte=l 
+__vsc_escape_value:10> [ l '=' '\' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:12> [ l '=' ';' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:15> token=l 
+__vsc_escape_value:18> out+=l 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> ++i 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> i < 16
+__vsc_escape_value:7> byte=d 
+__vsc_escape_value:10> [ d '=' '\' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:12> [ d '=' ';' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:15> token=d 
+__vsc_escape_value:18> out+=d 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> ++i 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> i < 16
+__vsc_escape_value:7> byte=' ' 
+__vsc_escape_value:10> [ ' ' '=' '\' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:12> [ ' ' '=' ';' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:15> token=' ' 
+__vsc_escape_value:18> out+=' ' 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> ++i 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> i < 16
+__vsc_escape_value:7> byte=n 
+__vsc_escape_value:10> [ n '=' '\' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:12> [ n '=' ';' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:15> token=n 
+__vsc_escape_value:18> out+=n 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> ++i 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> i < 16
+__vsc_escape_value:7> byte=o 
+__vsc_escape_value:10> [ o '=' '\' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:12> [ o '=' ';' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:15> token=o 
+__vsc_escape_value:18> out+=o 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> ++i 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> i < 16
+__vsc_escape_value:7> byte=a 
+__vsc_escape_value:10> [ a '=' '\' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:12> [ a '=' ';' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:15> token=a 
+__vsc_escape_value:18> out+=a 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> ++i 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> i < 16
+__vsc_escape_value:7> byte=h 
+__vsc_escape_value:10> [ h '=' '\' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:12> [ h '=' ';' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:15> token=h 
+__vsc_escape_value:18> out+=h 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> ++i 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> i < 16
+__vsc_escape_value:7> byte=- 
+__vsc_escape_value:10> [ - '=' '\' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:12> [ - '=' ';' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:15> token=- 
+__vsc_escape_value:18> out+=- 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> ++i 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> i < 16
+__vsc_escape_value:7> byte=o 
+__vsc_escape_value:10> [ o '=' '\' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:12> [ o '=' ';' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:15> token=o 
+__vsc_escape_value:18> out+=o 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> ++i 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> i < 16
+__vsc_escape_value:7> byte=s 
+__vsc_escape_value:10> [ s '=' '\' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:12> [ s '=' ';' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:15> token=s 
+__vsc_escape_value:18> out+=s 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> ++i 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> i < 16
+__vsc_escape_value:21> print -r 'nx build noah-os'
+__vsc_command_output_start:2> printf '\e]633;E;%s\a' 'nx build noah-os'
+/bin/zsh:3> nx build noah-os

> nx run noah-os:build  [local cache]


Initial Chunk Files                                                                                     | Names                                                                   |  Raw Size
vendor.js                                                                                               | vendor                                                                  |   8.82 MB | 
main.js                                                                                                 | main                                                                    |   3.70 MB | 
dhtmlx-spreadsheet.js                                                                                   | dhtmlx-spreadsheet                                                      |   1.89 MB | 
dhtmlx-dhtmlxscheduler.js                                                                               | dhtmlx-dhtmlxscheduler                                                  |   1.08 MB | 
polyfills.js                                                                                            | polyfills                                                               | 978.25 kB | 
mainstyles.css                                                                                          | mainstyles                                                              | 615.32 kB | 
scripts.js                                                                                              | scripts                                                                 | 221.90 kB | 
runtime.js[39m                                                                                              | runtime                                                                 |  13.36 kB | 

                                                                                                        | Initial Total                                                           |  17.27 MB

Lazy Chunk Files                                                                                        | Names                                                                   |  Raw Size
apps_noah-os_src_app_pages_scheduling_scheduling_module_ts.js                                           | fe-pages-scheduling-scheduling-module                                   |   1.15 MB | 
....
apps_noah-os_src_app_pages_contracts_contracts_module_ts.js                                             | fe-pages-contracts-contracts-module                                     |   4.32 kB | 

Build at: 2023-03-29T19:17:03.538Z - Hash: 6f0ff3e5aa9953f5 - Time: 76773ms

 —————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————

 >  NX   Successfully ran target build for project noah-os (302ms)
 
   Nx read the output from the cache instead of running the command for 1 out of 1 tasks.
 
+omz_termsupport_precmd:1> [[ '' != true ]]                                                                                                                                                        
+omz_termsupport_precmd:2> title '%15<..<%~%<<' '%n@%m:%~'
+title:1> setopt localoptions nopromptsubst
+title:4> [[ -n '' ]]
+title:8> : '%n@%m:%~'
+title:10> case xterm-256color (cygwin | xterm*)
+title:12> print -Pn '\e]2;%n@%m:%~\a'
+title:13> print -Pn '\e]1;%15\<..\<%~%\<\<\a'
+__vsc_precmd:1> local __vsc_status=0
+__vsc_precmd:2> [ -z 1 ']'
+__vsc_precmd:7> __vsc_command_complete 0
+__vsc_command_complete:1> [[ 'nx build noah-os' ==  ]]
+__vsc_command_complete:4> printf '\e]633;D;%s\a' 0
+__vsc_command_complete:6> __vsc_update_cwd
+__vsc_update_cwd:1> __vsc_escape_value /Users/fribu/Sites/noah/noah-fe
+__vsc_escape_value:1> emulate -L zsh
+__vsc_escape_value:4> local 'LC_ALL=C' 'str=/Users/fribu/Sites/noah/noah-fe' i byte token 'out='
+__vsc_escape_value:6> i = 0
+__vsc_escape_value:6> i < 31
+__vsc_escape_value:7> byte=/ 
+__vsc_escape_value:10> [ / '=' '\' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:12> [ / '=' ';' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:15> token=/ 
+__vsc_escape_value:18> out+=/ 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> ++i 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> i < 31
+__vsc_escape_value:7> byte=U 
+__vsc_escape_value:10> [ U '=' '\' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:12> [ U '=' ';' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:15> token=U 
+__vsc_escape_value:18> out+=U 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> ++i 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> i < 31
+__vsc_escape_value:7> byte=s 
+__vsc_escape_value:10> [ s '=' '\' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:12> [ s '=' ';' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:15> token=s 
+__vsc_escape_value:18> out+=s 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> ++i 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> i < 31
+__vsc_escape_value:7> byte=e 
+__vsc_escape_value:10> [ e '=' '\' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:12> [ e '=' ';' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:15> token=e 
+__vsc_escape_value:18> out+=e 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> ++i 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> i < 31
+__vsc_escape_value:7> byte=r 
+__vsc_escape_value:10> [ r '=' '\' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:12> [ r '=' ';' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:15> token=r 
+__vsc_escape_value:18> out+=r 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> ++i 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> i < 31
+__vsc_escape_value:7> byte=s 
+__vsc_escape_value:10> [ s '=' '\' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:12> [ s '=' ';' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:15> token=s 
+__vsc_escape_value:18> out+=s 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> ++i 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> i < 31
+__vsc_escape_value:7> byte=/ 
+__vsc_escape_value:10> [ / '=' '\' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:12> [ / '=' ';' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:15> token=/ 
+__vsc_escape_value:18> out+=/ 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> ++i 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> i < 31
+__vsc_escape_value:7> byte=f 
+__vsc_escape_value:10> [ f '=' '\' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:12> [ f '=' ';' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:15> token=f 
+__vsc_escape_value:18> out+=f 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> ++i 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> i < 31
+__vsc_escape_value:7> byte=r 
+__vsc_escape_value:10> [ r '=' '\' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:12> [ r '=' ';' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:15> token=r 
+__vsc_escape_value:18> out+=r 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> ++i 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> i < 31
+__vsc_escape_value:7> byte=i 
+__vsc_escape_value:10> [ i '=' '\' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:12> [ i '=' ';' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:15> token=i 
+__vsc_escape_value:18> out+=i 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> ++i 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> i < 31
+__vsc_escape_value:7> byte=b 
+__vsc_escape_value:10> [ b '=' '\' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:12> [ b '=' ';' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:15> token=b 
+__vsc_escape_value:18> out+=b 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> ++i 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> i < 31
+__vsc_escape_value:7> byte=u 
+__vsc_escape_value:10> [ u '=' '\' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:12> [ u '=' ';' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:15> token=u 
+__vsc_escape_value:18> out+=u 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> ++i 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> i < 31
+__vsc_escape_value:7> byte=/ 
+__vsc_escape_value:10> [ / '=' '\' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:12> [ / '=' ';' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:15> token=/ 
+__vsc_escape_value:18> out+=/ 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> ++i 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> i < 31
+__vsc_escape_value:7> byte=S 
+__vsc_escape_value:10> [ S '=' '\' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:12> [ S '=' ';' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:15> token=S 
+__vsc_escape_value:18> out+=S 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> ++i 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> i < 31
+__vsc_escape_value:7> byte=i 
+__vsc_escape_value:10> [ i '=' '\' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:12> [ i '=' ';' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:15> token=i 
+__vsc_escape_value:18> out+=i 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> ++i 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> i < 31
+__vsc_escape_value:7> byte=t 
+__vsc_escape_value:10> [ t '=' '\' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:12> [ t '=' ';' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:15> token=t 
+__vsc_escape_value:18> out+=t 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> ++i 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> i < 31
+__vsc_escape_value:7> byte=e 
+__vsc_escape_value:10> [ e '=' '\' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:12> [ e '=' ';' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:15> token=e 
+__vsc_escape_value:18> out+=e 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> ++i 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> i < 31
+__vsc_escape_value:7> byte=s 
+__vsc_escape_value:10> [ s '=' '\' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:12> [ s '=' ';' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:15> token=s 
+__vsc_escape_value:18> out+=s 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> ++i 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> i < 31
+__vsc_escape_value:7> byte=/ 
+__vsc_escape_value:10> [ / '=' '\' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:12> [ / '=' ';' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:15> token=/ 
+__vsc_escape_value:18> out+=/ 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> ++i 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> i < 31
+__vsc_escape_value:7> byte=n 
+__vsc_escape_value:10> [ n '=' '\' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:12> [ n '=' ';' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:15> token=n 
+__vsc_escape_value:18> out+=n 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> ++i 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> i < 31
+__vsc_escape_value:7> byte=o 
+__vsc_escape_value:10> [ o '=' '\' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:12> [ o '=' ';' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:15> token=o 
+__vsc_escape_value:18> out+=o 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> ++i 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> i < 31
+__vsc_escape_value:7> byte=a 
+__vsc_escape_value:10> [ a '=' '\' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:12> [ a '=' ';' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:15> token=a 
+__vsc_escape_value:18> out+=a 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> ++i 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> i < 31
+__vsc_escape_value:7> byte=h 
+__vsc_escape_value:10> [ h '=' '\' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:12> [ h '=' ';' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:15> token=h 
+__vsc_escape_value:18> out+=h 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> ++i 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> i < 31
+__vsc_escape_value:7> byte=/ 
+__vsc_escape_value:10> [ / '=' '\' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:12> [ / '=' ';' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:15> token=/ 
+__vsc_escape_value:18> out+=/ 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> ++i 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> i < 31
+__vsc_escape_value:7> byte=n 
+__vsc_escape_value:10> [ n '=' '\' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:12> [ n '=' ';' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:15> token=n 
+__vsc_escape_value:18> out+=n 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> ++i 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> i < 31
+__vsc_escape_value:7> byte=o 
+__vsc_escape_value:10> [ o '=' '\' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:12> [ o '=' ';' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:15> token=o 
+__vsc_escape_value:18> out+=o 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> ++i 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> i < 31
+__vsc_escape_value:7> byte=a 
+__vsc_escape_value:10> [ a '=' '\' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:12> [ a '=' ';' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:15> token=a 
+__vsc_escape_value:18> out+=a 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> ++i 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> i < 31
+__vsc_escape_value:7> byte=h 
+__vsc_escape_value:10> [ h '=' '\' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:12> [ h '=' ';' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:15> token=h 
+__vsc_escape_value:18> out+=h 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> ++i 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> i < 31
+__vsc_escape_value:7> byte=- 
+__vsc_escape_value:10> [ - '=' '\' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:12> [ - '=' ';' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:15> token=- 
+__vsc_escape_value:18> out+=- 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> ++i 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> i < 31
+__vsc_escape_value:7> byte=f 
+__vsc_escape_value:10> [ f '=' '\' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:12> [ f '=' ';' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:15> token=f 
+__vsc_escape_value:18> out+=f 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> ++i 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> i < 31
+__vsc_escape_value:7> byte=e 
+__vsc_escape_value:10> [ e '=' '\' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:12> [ e '=' ';' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:15> token=e 
+__vsc_escape_value:18> out+=e 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> ++i 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> i < 31
+__vsc_escape_value:21> print -r /Users/fribu/Sites/noah/noah-fe
+__vsc_update_cwd:1> printf '\e]633;P;Cwd=%s\a' /Users/fribu/Sites/noah/noah-fe
+__vsc_precmd:8> __vsc_current_command='' 
+__vsc_precmd:11> [ -n 1 ']'
+__vsc_precmd:13> __vsc_update_prompt
+__vsc_update_prompt:1> __vsc_prior_prompt=$'%(?:%{\C-[[01;32m%}➜ :%{\C-[[01;31m%}➜ ) %{$fg[cyan]%}%c%{$reset_color%} $(git_prompt_info)' 
+__vsc_update_prompt:2> __vsc_prior_prompt2='%_> ' 
+__vsc_update_prompt:3> __vsc_in_command_execution='' 
+__vsc_update_prompt:4> PS1=+__vsc_update_prompt:4> __vsc_prompt_start
+__vsc_prompt_start:1> printf '\e]633;A\a'
+__vsc_update_prompt:4> PS1=+__vsc_update_prompt:4> __vsc_prompt_end
+__vsc_prompt_end:1> printf '\e]633;B\a'
+__vsc_update_prompt:4> PS1=$'%{\C-[]633;A\C-G%}%(?:%{\C-[[01;32m%}➜ :%{\C-[[01;31m%}➜ ) %{$fg[cyan]%}%c%{$reset_color%} $(git_prompt_info)%{\C-[]633;B\C-G%}' 
+__vsc_update_prompt:5> PS2=+__vsc_update_prompt:5> __vsc_continuation_start
+__vsc_continuation_start:1> printf '\e]633;F\a'
+__vsc_update_prompt:5> PS2=+__vsc_update_prompt:5> __vsc_continuation_end
+__vsc_continuation_end:1> printf '\e]633;G\a'
+__vsc_update_prompt:5> PS2=$'%{\C-[]633;F\C-G%}%_> %{\C-[]633;G\C-G%}' 
+__vsc_update_prompt:6> [ -n '' ']'
+/bin/zsh:4> git_prompt_info
+git_prompt_info:3> __git_prompt_git rev-parse --git-dir
+git_prompt_info:4> [[+git_prompt_info:4> __git_prompt_git config --get oh-my-zsh.hide-info
+git_prompt_info:4> [[ '' == 1 ]]
+git_prompt_info:8> local ref
+git_prompt_info:9> ref=+git_prompt_info:9> __git_prompt_git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
+git_prompt_info:9> ref=develop 
+git_prompt_info:14> local upstream
+git_prompt_info:15> ((  0  ))
+git_prompt_info:20> parse_git_dirty
+parse_git_dirty:1> local STATUS
+parse_git_dirty:2> local -a FLAGS
+parse_git_dirty:3> FLAGS=( --porcelain ) 
+parse_git_dirty:4> [[+parse_git_dirty:4> __git_prompt_git config --get oh-my-zsh.hide-dirty
+__git_prompt_git:1> GIT_OPTIONAL_LOCKS=0 git config --get oh-my-zsh.hide-dirty
+parse_git_dirty:4> [[ '' != 1 ]]
+parse_git_dirty:5> [[ '' == true ]]
+parse_git_dirty:8> case  (git)
+parse_git_dirty:8> case  (*)
+parse_git_dirty:15> FLAGS+='--ignore-submodules=dirty' 
+parse_git_dirty:18> STATUS=+parse_git_dirty:18> STATUS=+parse_git_dirty:18> tail -n 1
+parse_git_dirty:18> STATUS='' 
+parse_git_dirty:20> [[ -n '' ]]
+parse_git_dirty:23> echo $'%{\C-[[34m%})'
+git_prompt_info:20> echo $'%{\C-[[01;34m%}git:(%{\C-[[31m%}develop%{\C-[[34m%})%{\C-[[00m%} '
```

Comment: This is behavior of yarn, not bash. (Do we have a close reason for "based on a false premise"?)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy it's not yarn issue, if I run the command directly, there result is the same

Comment: If you start your command with, say, Python's `subprocess.run(['yarn', 'build'], shell=False)` you'll see the same behavior with no shell involved anywhere.

Comment: That said, if you think there might be a shell function overriding the shell's default behavior, run `set -x` to enable trace logging.

Comment: "if I run the command directly, there result is the same" -- I clearly am misunderstanding what you mean by this, because I don't see how it implies anything about the shell performing caching. (Maybe go into more details about what you mean by "the command" or "directly"). But this is all moot if enabling trace logging shows some kind of caching taking place, of course, or -- more likely -- if it _doesn't_.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy again, if I had a clue about what this might be caused by, I would google it. This is the best guess I had. I used to run tests with `ng test` the tests run well, then one day this problem appear, and the test finished under 1 second. I tried to experiment with options, and i looked like it helped. At least for the moment. But it is a remaining problem.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I have added the set -X output. Not sure what to look for :)

Comment: Reading through it so far, it looks like it's mostly about figuring out how to print your prompt, and not about caching.

Comment: Think about `set -x; yarn build; set +x` to have trace logging turned on for the `yarn build` but not for while your prompt is being printed.

Comment: (there's also a bunch of what I assume is oh-my-zsh support cruft, but it's only intercepting specific commands like `fg`; I don't see it trying to muck with nx from what I can tell).

Comment: ...to be clear, it's very normal for adding options to invalidate a cache, if your caching system is well-designed; but that's not evidence that the shell is involved in that caching mechanism; it's just mechanism that there _is_ a caching mechanism somewhere downstream, and that's normal for any reasonably mature build ecosystem.

Comment: Anyhow -- could I ask you to explain like I'm 5, with respect to supporting evidence to think that this is a shell feature as opposed to a yarn or npx feature?

Comment: _if I run the command directly, ..._ What do you mean by "directly"? Just `build` instead of `yarn build`? This does not make sense to me.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the terminal or your shell. You have simply demonstrated that two build tools (`yarn` and `nx`) do what build tools are supposed to do: *not* rebuild things that haven't changed since the last build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im sure answer can be pretty easy, just try to make

```
nx clear-cache
```

before your tests